# Get abid from Contact Framework iOS

Tags: ios, whatsapp

I'm trying to get the abid on the new apple's `Contacts Framework`.

I want to create an whatsapp scheme URL to open an specific contact's conversation and found at the documentation that `CNContact` has a constant called `CNContactIdentifierKey` but it's seems not works.

```
 NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@&abid=%@",text ,mc.abid]];
 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
      NSLog(@"%@", whatsappURL);
 }
```

mc.abid is giving to me a string like this: `86BA6C28-74E5-4A32-A270-5D18C2DFCD3B`.

any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Official Whatsapp API solution

I believe you should solve your need with the new Whatsapp official solution I mentioned in [THIS OTHER ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45227158/1920145) (because S.O. policies I had to put a link to the solution, no duplicates).